# What is the difference between 'require' and 'config.gem' in a RoR app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

What is the difference between having `require 'gem_name'` in a controller and `config.gem "gem_name"` in environments.rb? I'm new to RoR, and am looking through an app and can't work out the difference. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.gem in your environment.rb is needed to set up the correct rails environment.  For example if you download a ruby app from github you can run rake gems:install from the application directory and all the correct versions of the required gems will be installed.

require in a controller is like import in vb.net and allows the classes in that gem to be used in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

"environments.rb" is a file that contains various configuration setting for your application, e.g. which gem the application needs to run correctly (mainly for portability). They have to be specified using config.gem "gem_name". [This post](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/4/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-gem-dependencies) about Gem Dependencies could help you.

With [require](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/4) "gem_name" you can explictly import a gem into your code in order to be able to use it´s classes.